# google drive / list file names from public folder .net c#

Tags: directory, filenames, google-drive-api, public

I would like to list out file names from a certain public folder from google drive, I am aware of Google SDK, but I would need only a list of file names from a google drive folder.
I would appreciate any directions for a simple solution for it.

Thanks